# Error de sintaxis en CREATE FUNCTION mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sintaxis

No suelo realizar funciones en mariadb, por lo que al crear una me aparece un error de sintaxis al querer compilarla. He visto varios ejemplos pero no encuentro mi error. Quizas ustedes si puedan indicarme donde falle. Gracias

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION codigo_individual_correctos (codigo_individual INT) RETURNS BOOLEAN 
BEGIN
DECLARE numRegistros INT

DECLARE codigoGlobal INT

DECLARE codigoEspejo INT

numRegistros = SELECT COUNT(*) registros FROM registro_entradas_individual ri WHERE ri.corrida_global = (
    SELECT  ris.corrida_global  FROM registro_entradas_individual ris WHERE ris.codigo_individual = codigo_individual)

codigoGlobal = SELECT ris.corrida_global FROM registro_entradas_individual ris WHERE ris.codigo_individual = codigo_individual
#Si existen mas de 1 registro verificar que el codigo recibido sea el ultimo
 IF numRegistros >1 THEN 
 codigoEspejo = SELECT rei.codigo_individual ,  rei .fecha_ingreso FROM registro_entradas_individual rei WHERE
 rei.estatus_individual = 1 AND rei .vendido = 0 AND rei .corrida_global = codigoGlobal ORDER BY rei .fecha_ingreso DESC limit 1

    IF codigoEspejo == codigo_individual THEN
        RETURN TRUE
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE
    END IF
ELSE 

RETURN TRUE

END IF
END //
delimiter;
```

[image: Datos del error]

Sobre añadir ; despues de declarar las variables, ya lo habia intentado pero al hacerlo me aparecen mas errores, y sigue sin compilar

[image: Al agregar ; despues de las variables]

Comment: Agrega por favor el mensaje exacto del error

Comment: Ponle ';' al término de cada sentencia `DECLARE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, no sé cuál versión de MySQL estas ocupando.
Segundo estas usando un `DECLARE` y no lo tomas con el `SET`, y al llamar una función no lo colocas entre paréntesis `()`.
Segundo, en tu `IF` estás usando un operador `==`que no soporta MYSQL.
Tercero no agregas `;` a tus `END IF`

No se si te funcione, pero prueba con esto:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  FUNCTION codigo_individual_correctos (codigo_individual INT) RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
    DECLARE numRegistros INT;
    DECLARE codigoGlobal INT;
    DECLARE codigoEspejo INT;

    SET numRegistros = (SELECT COUNT(*) registros FROM registro_entradas_individual ri WHERE ri.corrida_global) = (
    SELECT  ris.corrida_global  FROM registro_entradas_individual ris WHERE ris.codigo_individual = codigo_individual);
    SET codigoGlobal = (SELECT ris.corrida_global FROM registro_entradas_individual ris WHERE ris.codigo_individual = codigo_individual);
            IF numRegistros >1 THEN
                SET codigoEspejo = (SELECT rei.codigo_individual ,  rei.fecha_ingreso FROM registro_entradas_individual rei WHERE
                rei.estatus_individual = 1 AND rei.vendido = 0 AND rei.corrida_global = codigoGlobal ORDER BY rei.fecha_ingreso DESC limit 1);
                IF (codigoEspejo = codigo_individual) THEN
                    RETURN TRUE;
                ELSE
                        RETURN FALSE;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                RETURN TRUE;      
            END IF;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Gracias, si funcionaron tus correcciones. Voy a comparar mi codigo para poder ver bien las indicaciones que hiciste. Gracias